# Задача на вложенный запрос MS SQL. Нужна помощь в решении

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы

```
Create table [employees]
(Persona_id, Name, Dates_birthday, Job_position, Experience, Location_Id)

Create table [location]
( Location_ID, City, Address, Desk)
```

Нужно **вывести местоположение  - город самого старшего  или старших по возрасту** сотрудника, если их даты рождения идентичны.

То есть если у нескольких сотрудников день рождения 01-01-1990, то запрос должен вывести города этих сотрудников.

Пробовал так, но он только выдает локацию и имя.

```
Select e.Location_ID, e.Name from [employees] e  
where e.Dates_Birthday  = ( Select Dates_Birthday = min (Dates_Birthday) from employees )
```

**Помогите докрутить запрос**!!!

Comment: дак присоедините таблицу местоположений-то

Comment: @teran можете продемонстрировать ответ, пожалуйста ? 
Необходим еще один вложенный селект ?

Answer (score 0):

В SQL есть оператор [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), который позволяет объединить данные из двух таблиц (т.е. результат будет содержать данные из двух таблиц).

```
select *
from employees emp
inner join location loc on emp.Location_Id = loc.Location_ID
```

Такой запрос выдаст вам всех работников, вместе с их местоположениями. `on` - после этого оператора идет условие на основание которого будет происходить объединение (т.е. в вашем случае, оно будет "смотреть" на значение Location_Id у работника и находить местоположение с **равным** значением Location_Id).

И для вашей задачи остается добавить только `where` условие и вместо всех колонок выводить только те, что необходимы.

Если именно нужно сделать через подзапрос, то можно:

```
Select 
  (select loc.City from location loc where loc.Location_Id = e.Location_ID) as location, 
  e.Name 
from [employees] e 
where e.Dates_Birthday  = ( Select Dates_Birthday = min (Dates_Birthday) from employees )
```